# Angular interpolation cannot access object

Tags: angular, string-interpolation

This is for an Angular project. I need to access an object in my template that's already in my component. I see the object when I console log it, but when I try to access it, nothing happens. Please note that what I'm trying to do is to filter an object by a specific name.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {SwapiService} from "../../models/swapi.service";
import {BehaviorSubject, Subject} from "rxjs";
import {Pilot, Starship} from "../../models/starship";
import {MatTableDataSource} from "@angular/material/table";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-starship',
  templateUrl: './starship.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./starship.component.css']
})
export class StarshipComponent implements OnInit {
  public starship: Starship;
  public name: string;
  public crew: number;
  public pilots: Pilot[];
  public index;
 


  constructor(private swapi: SwapiService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.name = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');
     }


  loadStarship(): void {
    this.swapi.getStarshipList().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.starship = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));
        this.swapi.setData(res)
        this.crew = this.starship.crew;
        console.log(this.crew);
        console.log(this.starship[0]);

        console.log(this.name);

        console.log(res);
      }
    )
  }



  ngOnInit(){
    this.loadStarship();
    
  }


}
```

my template

```
<p *ngIf="starship">{{starship.crew}}</p>
<p>{{starship.name}}</p>
```

please note that starship.name does work because of activated route, but crew doesn't I've tried EVERything!!

my response in Json:

```
Angular is running in development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable production mode.
main.js:42 undefined
main.js:43 {name: "CR90 corvette", model: "CR90 corvette", manufacturer: "Corellian Engineering Corporation", cost_in_credits: "3500000", length: "150", …}MGLT: "60"cargo_capacity: "3000000"consumables: "1 year"cost_in_credits: "3500000"created: "2014-12-10T14:20:33.369000Z"crew: "30-165"edited: "2014-12-20T21:23:49.867000Z"films: (3) ["http://swapi.dev/api/films/1/", "http://swapi.dev/api/films/3/", "http://swapi.dev/api/films/6/"]hyperdrive_rating: "2.0"length: "150"manufacturer: "Corellian Engineering Corporation"max_atmosphering_speed: "950"model: "CR90 corvette"name: "CR90 corvette"passengers: "600"pilots: []starship_class: "corvette"url: "http://swapi.dev/api/starships/2/"__proto__: Object
main.js:44 Star Destroyer
main.js:45 (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The API response is an array of starships, not a single ship. Here `this.starship = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))` you put the entire fleet in your `starship` variable, therefore `starship.name` will be undefined.

Change the assignment to `this.starship = res[0]` and you'll see the name.

Comment: it only gives me the results for the first object. But if I want it for the third object?. The name changes according to the name from Activated Route, but not all the other variables. How can make the index res[0] change when the name changes